# In kendo ui How to Collapsing Graph could expand table but expanding graph then bring both the graph and table to be visible too

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

collapsing Graph could expand table but expanding graph immediately shall bring both the graph and table to be visible too,Vice versa.

Comment: Here is js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/269/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement a [`collapse`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#collapse) and [`expand`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#expand) function handlers.

```
 $("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
     expandMode: "single",
     expand: function (e) {
         ...
     },
     collapse: function (e) {
         ...
     }
 });
```

On these handlers you check which item is being collapsed (or expanded) and decide which ones to [`expand`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#expand) and [`collapse`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#collapse) according to your algorithm.

For knowing which item is being collapse / expanded you should use inside the handler:

```
var itemId = $("span", e.item).attr("id");
```

The very last thing is remember that if you want more than one bars opened you should switch you [`expandMode`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/panelbar#expandmode-stringdefault) to multiple.

**EDIT:** As first approach to what you need:

```
$("#panelbar").kendoPanelBar({
    expandMode: "multiple",
    expand    : function (e) {
        var itemId = $("span", e.item).attr("id");
        if (itemId === "Span1") {
            this.expand($("#Span2").closest("li"));
        } else {
            this.collapse($("Span1").closest("li"));
        }
    },
    collapse  : function (e) {
        var itemId = $("span", e.item).attr("id");
        if (itemId === "Span1") {
            this.expand($("#Span2").closest("li"));
        } else {
            this.collapse($("Span1").closest("li"));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Here how to fix the stock chart  to the page size? i already fixed the grid but stockchart is not elaborate to page size when grid is collapsed.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: here is  the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MG89G/278/                 my requriment is when the grid is collapsed  the below reminig space should be filled with kendo stock graph and fit to the  browser page size.